# Convert string to hexadecimal with "0x" and leading 0s in Python

Tags: python, format, hex, registry, winreg

I want to change a registry key value via Python. The value type will be `REG_DWORD` which means hexadecimal including `0x000` in integer format. I am having trouble converting a string with a number to its hexadecimal format in integer.

Since I am looping through a number of registry keys, my code to change a certain key is as follows:

```
for i in range(len(checking_names)): #loop through names to check 
    if checking_names(i) !== should_values(i): #no match
        with winreg.CreateKeyEx(key, subkey_path, 0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS) as subkey: 
            winreg.DeleteValue(subkey, names_data[i]) #have to delete name in order to overwrite
            winreg.SetValueEx(subkey, names_data[i], 0, winreg.REG_DWORD, new_hex_value) #overwrite name value with correct value from predefined list
```

My `values_data` list is comprised of predefined variables as strings. One of the entries is a string `'9600'`. In my above code, `values_data[i]` should be 9600 in hexadecimal format: `0x00002580`. For this conversion I do the following:

```
dec_to_hex_str = format(int(values_data[i]),'x') #string decimal to string hexadecimal conversion
zeros_pre_x    = '0x' #0x for format 0xffffffff

zeros_to_add   = 8 - len(dec_to_hex_str) #count number of leading 0s to add
mid_zeros_list = []
for j in range(zeros_to_add):  
    mid_zeros_list.append(0) #add a leading 0
mid_zeros = ''.join(mid_zeros_list) #convert list to string

new_hex_value = int(zeros_pre_hex + mid_zeros + dec_to_hex_str)
```

When I run this code, my Python shell is unresponsive, and there is no change in the Windows registry for the `subkey` value. The problem seems to be, that `winreg.SetValueEx .... winreg.REG_DWORD` only understands integer format but my `new_hex_value` is not being properly converted from string to integer.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If it only takes integers, why you do `str -> int -> hex_str` instead of `str -> int`.

Comment: Also, you are appending the zeroes, not prepending them.

Comment: I do not quite understand your first point. Using `format()` outputs a string. I then use strings for the concatenation. The concatenated output I convert to integer resulting in the variable `new_hex_value`

Comment: Does the number change from the original value to new_hex_value ?

Comment: Yes. For example 9600 gives me 2580 for new_hex_value but is formatted as a string

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the line

```py
new_hex_value = int(zeros_pre_hex + mid_zeros + dec_to_hex_str)
```

You are converting the number to a hex string, then converting it into an integer.  Not only is this an invalid argument to `int()`, but even if it were correct, you would just be converting it back to an integer (there is no such thing as a hex integer in Python).  So your line should read:

```py
new_hex_value = zeros_pre_hex + mid_zeros + dec_to_hex_str
```

Then simply write this as a `REG_SZ` because you want a hex string, not an integer.  There is no "hex integer" in the registry either.

Comment: Thanks, my script is not unresponsive anymore. However, if I convert the type to `REG_SZ`, I can't use that registry input for my program anymore, since my program needs the `REG_DWORD` format to be able to read the number and apply it accordingly.

Comment: @needhelp123456 `REG_DWORD` isn't hex or decimal, the only way to store a number as hex is to use `REG_SZ` or another string value.  Can you explain why storing it as a `REG_DWORD` isn't working?

Comment: a program is started with the configuration stored in that registry key. the value that i am trying to change is the baudrate for the program. the default format with which the baudrate looks like this `BAUDRATE        REG_DWORD       0x00002580 (9600)`. and I tried `SetValueEx` by typing `0x00002580` rather than getting the value from a variable, and it worked.